# NodeJS send request without request from client

Tags: php, android, node.js, laravel

i'm newbie in nodejs and i want to send data to client without send request from client, for example i want to after create new data in database like with mysql trigger nodjs fetch data from database and send necessary data to client. in other language programing we try to create Thread to fetch such as database or send JSON object every one secode, how to this ability in NodeJS?

```
var server   = require('http').createServer(),
    io    = require('socket.io').listen(server),
    mysql = require('mysql'),
    express =   require('express'),
    fs    = require('fs');

server.listen(3000, 'localhost');
console.log("connected...");
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'node'
});

io.listen(server).on('connection', function(client) {
    /* FETCH DATA IF NECESSERY AND IF DATA INSERTED IN DB OR UPDATE OR DELETE*/
    console.log("data send");

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The rule is: When the client connects to the server, you store the identifier of the connection (for future use) 
When a specific event occurs on the server side and want to transmit information to the client, fastening the stored credentials 
With Socket Web, the server does not require that the client starts the communication (as long as the connection is maintained by the server and the client)

You can do as follow :

```
    // it can be 2 dimensional array USER_ID, SOCKET
    var STORED_SOCKET = new Array () ;

    // ...
    io.listen(server).on('connection', function (client) {
        /* FETCH DATA IF NECESSERY AND IF DATA INSERTED IN DB OR UPDATE OR DELETE*/
        STORED_SOCKET.push( client) ;
        console.log("data send");

    });

    // -- if something happend in mysql, you browse your STORED_SOCKET array, find the concerned user and send him data
    function mysqlEvent (userId, yourData) {    
        for ( i = 0 ; i < STORED_SOCKET.length ; i++ ) {
            if (STORED_SOCKET[i]['USER_ID'] == userId) {
                STORED_SOCKET[i].volatile.emit( yourData ) ;
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it is clear :)

Comment: thank you very much sir. can you help me to how to get connected device socket for send only data for it?

Comment: so i have to ask you : how you identify the connected users in your system, do you use which mechanism ?

Comment: HI, in my application i'm register users by username,password and email. i want to after opening app in android i can get user connected socket and if user have message i must be can send only data if necessery to user selected socket whitout send request from device, thats mus be realtime, :)