# How to send res to my client using cron jobs

Tags: node.js, cron, sails.js, node-cron

I have cron jobs launch when server start that watch and start an appointment when it's time come but I want to send data to my client through response ,is that possible in cron jobs

I am working with NodeJS and sails

```
crons.schedule("* * * * * *", async (req, res) => {
  res.send("appointment started")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this, cause you don't have access to req & res objects

Comment: is there is any other way to send data to client without using res or socket.io

Comment: @mohamednageh you can look here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28586709/nodejs-send-request-without-request-from-client) maybe it's help you

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Yuri Vorobev, CRON jobs in Sails do not have access to req and res objects. But what you can do is call a controller method/Action in the CRON job and send response at regular intervals.

Comment: I have called a controller in the cron jobs but it didn't send a response too , so let say I have this controller sendNotificatin (req,res ) how to call this in my cron job and send a response ?

Comment: Try `var sendNotificationController = rquire("./sendNotificationController.js");`. This way you can access all the controller methods. Eg: if there is a function called doSomething, then you can call it by `sendController.doSomething()`.

Comment: okay and the res how it will work on that case it will give no error @Prazhus

Comment: Do you have any strategy for sending response to the client without receiving a request from them ? But I feel it would be easier for you to use sockets.

Comment: I can do that yes without receiving a request but the issue how I will responded , yes socket.io is gonna work but I am looking for another way to do that